# How to select all products satisfying n numbers of attributeid/attributevalue conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Products table and ProductAttributeValues table

```
Product
-------
ID   1
Name A


ID   2
Name B

ProductAttributeValues
-------
ID          1
ProductID   1
AttributeID 1
Values  Z


ID          2
ProductID   1
AttributeID 2        1
Values  Y

ID          3
ProductID   1
AttributeID 3        1
Values  P
```

I need to select all products where,

```
((ProductAttributeValues.attrbuteid = X and ProductAttributeValues.Value = X)
 AND (ProductAttributeValues.attrbuteid = X and ProductAttributeValues.Value = X)
 AND ............................................................................
 AND ............................................................................)
```

These conditions are dynamic. So it might be 1 or 2 or 3 or so on.

So how to select all products satisfying n numbers of aattributeid/attribute value conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  I think the most general approach is aggregation with a `having` caluse:

```
select productID
from ProductAttributeValues pav
group by productID
having sum(case when ProductAttributeValues.attrbuteid = X and ProductAttributeValues.Value = X 
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ProductAttributeValues.attrbuteid = Y and ProductAttributeValues.Value = Y
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       . . .
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of attributes for each product that match the condition.  The overall clause is true when all the conditions have at least one row.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**
Use AttributeValues table multiple times in the join.

```
SELECT P.*
FROM 
Product P
JOIN ProductAttributeValues PA1 ON P.ID = PA1.ProductID AND PA1.AttributeID = X AND PA1.VALUES = X
JOIN ProductAttributeValues PA2 ON P.ID = PA2.ProductID AND PA2.AttributeID = Y AND PA2.VALUES = Y
JOIN ProductAttributeValues PA3 ON P.ID = PA3.ProductID AND PA3.AttributeID = Z AND PA3.VALUES = Z
..........And So on
```

**Method 2**
**Pivot** ProductAttributeValues table with AttributeID and AttributeValues as multiple columns. Now you can easily join your product and ProductAttributeValues to get the data you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product P
JOIN ProductAttributeValuesPivot PAP
ON P.ID = PAP.ProductID 
WHERE PAP.AttributeX = X AND PAP.ValueX = X
AND PAP.AttributeY = Y AND PAP.ValueY = Y
PAP.AttributeZ = Z AND PAP.ValueZ = Z
............... And So on
```

Links for Pivot 
[Dynamic Pivot Table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430512/dynamic-pivot-table-in-sql-server) 
[Technet Article for PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) 
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/create-pivoted-tables-3-steps