# How do i get multiple row into multiple column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need multiple row value into print column wise, could you help me.

```
Existing table values:
date    Emp ID  time

1/1/2014    111 1/1/2014 8:30 AM    
1/1/2014    222 1/1/2014 8:40 AM    
1/2/2014    111 1/2/2014 8:30 AM    
1/2/2014    222 1/2/2014 8:40 AM    
1/3/2014    111 1/3/2014 8:30 AM    
1/3/2014    222 1/3/2014 8:40 AM    
1/4/2014    111 1/4/2014 8:30 AM    
1/4/2014    222 1/4/2014 8:40 AM
```

I need output is,

```
Emp ID  1/1/2014        1/2/2014        1/3/2014        1/4/2014

111 1/1/2014 8:30 AM    1/2/2014 8:30 AM    1/3/2014 8:30 AM    1/4/2014 8:30 AM
222 1/1/2014 8:40 AM    1/2/2014 8:40 AM    1/3/2014 8:40 AM    1/4/2014 8:40 AM
```

Thanks for advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Pivot Table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430512/dynamic-pivot-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times before. Look at the answer posted here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12430701/1175077 It should be easy enough to adapt it to your specific tables.