# Group and sum with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am a begginer using this kind of query in SQL Server and I have a big table similar as I'm showing, the trouble that I have is that I don't know how to group and sum at the same time, I need to sum the SUP with every SIG with the code

```
  CODE      SIG  SUP
R501004002  BCO  30
R501004002  BCO  31.27
R501004008  BCO  34.09
R501004008  BCO  35.94
R501004003  MET  42
R501004020  RIP  42.5
R501004039  BCO  47.44
R501004020  RIP  68.56
```

The result that I want to show is something like this

```
CODE        BCO    MET  RIP
R501004002  61.27  0     0
R501004003  0      42    0
R501004008  70.03  0     0
R501004020   0     0     111.06
R501004039  47.44  0     0
```

I group the code

Comment: You may be after a dynamic pivot table.  stack has several such examples.  However, if you only have 3 sig's... then you could use case statements.  so do you have more than 3 sigs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only 3 sigs...

```
SELECT code
  , sum(case when sig = 'BCO' then sup else 0 end) as BCO
  , sum(case when sig = 'MET' then sup else 0 end) as MET
  , sum(case when sig = 'RIP' then sup else 0 end) as RIP
FROM tableName
GROUP BY code
```

otherwise use a dynamic pivot as exampled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430512/dynamic-pivot-table-in-sql-server)